# How to remove item from mutableList in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am scanning a list and adding an unique item in mutableList. Scanning a item through [ScanCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback) but below example is using for [Kotlin Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html) for better understanding and make a simple use case. I am giving an example of emiting different types of item.

Basically I want to remove items from the specific condtions :-

1. when flow data is finished to emit new values.
2. when emiting an item, if we no longer receive an item within 30 sec then we remove the item from the list.

   ```
   import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
   import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
   import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest
   import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
   import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

   class ItemList {
       val scanResultList = mutableListOf<ScanResults>()
       fun doSomething(): Flow<ScanResults> = flow {
          (0..20).forEach {
              delay(200L)
              when (it) {
                in 10..12 -> {
                    emit(ScanResults(Device("item is Adding in range of 10 -- 20")))
                }

                in 15..18 -> {
                    emit(ScanResults(Device("item is Adding in range of 15 -- 18")))
                }

                else -> {
                    emit(ScanResults(Device("item is Adding without range")))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun main() = runBlocking {
        doSomething().collectLatest { value ->
            handleScanResult(value)
        }
    }

    private fun handleScanResult(result: ScanResults) {
        if (!scanResultList.contains(result)) {
            result.device?.name?.let {
                if (hasNoDuplicateScanResult(scanResultList, result)) {
                    scanResultList.add(result)
                    println("Item added")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun hasNoDuplicateScanResult(value: List<ScanResults>, result: ScanResults): Boolean {
        return value.count { it.device == result.device } < 1
    }

    data class ScanResults(val device: Device? = null)
    data class Device(val name: String? = null)
   }
   ```

I am not adding `Set` because in [SnapshotStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/package-summary) is not available in jetpack compose.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `if (!scanResultList.equals(result))` since `result` is a ScanResults and `scanResultList` is a List. Did you mean `if (result !in scanResultsList)` ? Long term, I think you need to use `mutableStateListOf`, since I don't think MutableLists are compatible with State.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yea I mean `if (result !in scanResultsList)` means and hoe you can solve this question?

Comment: @Tenfour04 any update? I am using `mutableStateListOf ` but above example is basic and i was created in normal intellj project, so that's why I used `mutableListOf`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the description of what you're trying to do. When does step 1 occur--every time any collector finishes collecting on an instance of the flow? Should it be handled internally in the flow, or at the collection site? If it happens internally in the flow, do you want it to happen every time *any* collector finishes collecting it? For point 2, what happens if there are multiple concurrent collectors? You will have the same items being added to the list  multiple times, so which ones should be removed if they aren't replaced fast enough?

Comment: 1. Yes occurred every time after finishing and it will be done on collection site.

Comment: 2. When multiple data is coming ie 2-2-2-2-1-1-1....till 30 seconds if 2 is not come again then delete the 2 data from the list..

Comment: In list always unique item will be add

Comment: This example is just like when we scaning the item through Bluetooth and when we received any device we will show the list and if device is invisible then we need to remove the devixe from the list

Comment: @Tenfour04 you can think flow as [scanresult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback#onScanResult(int,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult))

Comment: The same thing which is emitting continue

Comment: BTW, you can use SnapshotStateMap as a set.

Comment: How can I use this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to reword the problem in simple terms. I'll say the input is a Flow of some imaginary data class `DeviceInfo` so it's easier to describe.

**Problem:**
There is a source flow of `DeviceInfo`s. We want our output to be a Flow of `Set<DeviceInfo>`, where the Set is all DeviceInfo's that have been emitted from the source in the past 30 seconds.

(If you want, you can convert this output Flow into State, or collect it and update a `mutablestateListOf` with it, etc.)

Here is a strategy I thought of. Disclaimer: I haven't tested it.

Tag each incoming DeviceInfo with a unique ID (could be based on system time or a UUID). Add each DeviceInfo to a Map with its latest ID. Launch a child coroutine that delays 30 seconds and then removes the item from the map if the ID matches. If newer values have arrived, then the ID won't match so obsolete child coroutines will expire silently.

```
val sourceFlow: Flow<DeviceInfo> = TODO()

val outputFlow: Flow<Set<DeviceInfo>> = flow {
    coroutineScope {
        val tagsByDeviceInfo = mutableMapOf<DeviceInfo, Long>()

        suspend fun emitLatest() = emit(tagsByDeviceInfo.keys.toSet())

        sourceFlow.collect { deviceInfo ->
            val id = System.currentTimeMillis()
            if (tagsByDeviceInfo.put(deviceInfo, id) == null) {
                emitLatest() // emit if the key was new to the map
            }
            launch {
                delay(30.seconds)
                if (tagsByDeviceInfo[deviceInfo] == id) {
                    tagsByDeviceInfo.remove(deviceInfo)
                    emitLatest()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```